# Implementing custom ember each handlebar helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to implement helper for following situation:

```
{{#inRange collection 1 3}}
    {{view App.SomeView content=this}}
{{/inRange}}
```

So purpose of this helper is to render only few items in some collection -> this is specified by second and third argument -> begin and end.

So far, I am trying with something like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('inRange', function (collection, start, end, options) {
  var res = '';
  var data = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, collection);
  data = data.slice(start, end);

  data.forEach(function (item) {
    res += options.fn(item);
  });

  return res;
});
```

But this doesn't work if I need to render `view` inside block helper. I looked into `native` Ember `each` implementation, but they are doing it on some other way.
They use something like this:

```
options.hash.dataSourceBinding = path;
return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.collection.call(this, 'Ember.Handlebars.EachView', options);
```

Problem with this is because I can't find any documentation about these lines of code.

Does anyone knows how I can make custom `each` helper, or knows something about how Ember `each` is working internally?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to learn the same.
But in your case rather than creating your own handlebar, its better to create a sub-collection as a property and pass it to `each` helper.

**in View class**

```
subCollection: function(){
   var collection = this.get('collection');
   return collection.slice(1,3);
}.property()
```

**in handlebars**

```
{{#each subCollection}}
    {{view App.SomeView content=this}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hmmm. I know for this workaround but I don't like it, because in this case code inside "View class" is totally unnecessary if you can have mentioned helper, and if you want to create multiple "subCollection-s", code inside view/controller will started to be dirty.